# Looking for a excel 2013 feature for google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Excel 2013 has a feature called forms (not to be confused with google forms) that ease data entry to microsoft excel spreadsheets , Heres a picture
[image: picture of it]

And a lifehacker [article](http://lifehacker.com/four-skills-that-will-turn-you-into-a-spreadsheet-ninj-1525058930) talking about it  . I feel this feature would be incredibly useful to those who do most/all of their work entering data in spreadsheets and making it vertical at the time of entry instead of horizontal would minimize mistakes , Is there anything similar for Google spreadsheets?

Comment: Why is this down voted so much?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming. I believe this question is better suited for [SU] or [WebApps.SE]. Before requesting migration, however, please check these sites to see if it hasn't already been answered there.

Answer (score 0):

You could build this as a sidebar in Apps Script, but ui building is down to your html/js knowledge

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs